# Trying to get the texts between this tag but getting an empty list

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

\Trying to get the texts A Plus and Computers from this html:

```
<div class="u-space-t1">
        <h1 class="biz-page-title embossed-text-white shortenough">A Plus</h1>
        <div class="u-inline-block">
            <h1 class="biz-page-title\ embossed-text-white\ shortenough">Computers</h1>
            <div class="u-inline-block">
```

So I tried to get the text like this:

```
c = soup.findAll('h1',{"class":"biz-page-title embossed-text-white shortenough"})

print(c)
```

However I am getting an empty list

I have tried doing this as well:

```
c = soup.find('div', class_='u-inline-block').h1
```

I am getting a 'Nonetype' object not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html = """
<div class="u-space-t1">
        <h1 class="biz-page-title embossed-text-white shortenough">A Plus</h1>
        <div class="u-inline-block">
            <h1 class="biz-page-title\ embossed-text-white\ shortenough">Computers</h1>
            <div class="u-inline-block"> 
"""

soup = bs4(html, 'lxml')
for i in soup.find_all('h1'):
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
A Plus
Computers
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

```
texts = soup.select("div > h1, div > div > h1")
for text in texts:
    print(text.text)
```

"A Plus" and "Computers" will come out.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However I am still printing something else.  Is there a way to be even more specific to finding the text.  Like using the class attribute for example?